# Powershell - What is the best way to extract sentences from string

Tags: string, powershell, text-extraction

I have text of many lines with the structure like this.

```
Sentence a. Sentence b part 1 `r`n
sentence b part 2. Sentence c.`r`n
Sentence d. Sentence e. Sentence f. `r`n
....
```

And I want to extract those the sentences and parts into an array of single strings for each part or a sentence.
As of now I found these the thing.

The first way.

```
$mySentences = $lineFromTheText -split "(?<=\.)"
```

The second way.

```
$mySentences = [regex]::matches($lineFromTheText, "([^.?!]+[.?!])?([^.?!]*$)?") | % {$_.Groups[1,2].Value} | % { If (-not ($_ -eq "")) {$_}}
```

And the third code.

```
$mySentences = ($lineFromTheText | Select-String -Pattern "([^.?!]+[.?!])?([^.?!]*$)?" -AllMatches).Matches  | % {$_.Groups[1,2].Value} | % { If (-not ($_ -eq "")) {$_}}
```

It seems all of these the code do the same thing for me as I'm expecting but I wonder of myself in this many of these the ways which code should I use. I mean what's the best code.
Please tell me know.
Thanks.

Comment: "The best code" depends on the metrics you did not provide. Do you want the shortest execution time? The least bytes of source code? Best human readable code? Least memory usage? All of them? If so, which metric should have which weight?

Comment: According to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), you would go for the first solution ;-)

Comment: How about performance efficent

Comment: Still ambiguous, CPU performance vs. memory performance? If you are looking for the fastest method, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the least execution time, you can just measure that. Let's run each solution 10000 times and let's see how long it takes:

```bsh
$lineFromTheText = "Sentence d. Sentence e. Sentence f."

(Measure-Command {1..10000 | % {$mySentences = $lineFromTheText -split "(?<=\.)"}}).Ticks
(Measure-Command {1..10000 | % {$mySentences = [regex]::matches($lineFromTheText, "([^.?!]+[.?!])?([^.?!]*$)?") | % {$_.Groups[1,2].Value} | % { If (-not ($_ -eq "")) {$_}}}}).Ticks
(Measure-Command {1..10000 | % {$mySentences = ($lineFromTheText | Select-String -Pattern "([^.?!]+[.?!])?([^.?!]*$)?" -AllMatches).Matches  | % {$_.Groups[1,2].Value} | % { If (-not ($_ -eq "")) {$_}}}}).Ticks
```

Output (example):

```
1059468
14512767
20444350
```

It looks like your first solution is the fastest and your third solution the slowest.